# Does the AppFabric Cache provider for ASP.Net Session State allow for a backing store?

Tags: asp.net, .net, appfabric-cache

AppFabric Cache may lose session state if there is RAM pressure on the cache cluster nodes, or  if the cluster is not in high availability mode and a node is lost (e.g. fails or is rebooted).

Typically a backing store would be used in those circumstances to allow the cache entry to be recreated in the event of a cache miss (it is a cache after all). Does the AppFabric Cache ASP.NET session state provider allow for a backing store, e.g. by forming a layer over one of the traditional session state providers? (such as ASP.NET State Service, or the SQL Server based provider).

Notes.

There is no mention of such a thing in the config documentation:

- [Configuring an ASP.NET Session State Provider (Windows Server AppFabric Caching)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790859%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)

Comment: AppFabric is for caching not storing : you can't know for sure when a cache entry is removed. If you want to be sure that your session won't be removed by the server use sql server session state provider instead.

Comment: @Remi - That's the question. Microsoft's standard session state provider seems to be using the cache as a store not as a cache, which may be a reasonable option if the cache is set to high-availability mode. Just trying to pull together info on whether this interpretation/understanding is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, this concept is unknow by AppFabric Session Provider because AppFabric is basically a distributed in-memory cache cluster. You can achieve persitence with Read-Through and Write-Behind but not for sessions.

You best option is to [plan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh334304%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) correctly you cache usage and actively [monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921021.aspx) the cluster.